# Why do packages depend on dpkg?

Tags: package-management, dependencies

I checked the transitive dependencies of many packages. They all depend on `dpkg`. I do not understand the reason. Does anyone know why?

Comment: An example may help.   Of course `apt` or `apt-get` will depend on `dpkg` (or `dpkg-dev`) but your question currently is too vague to be answered in a useful way.

Comment: Yes, `apt` would make complete sense. Examples of what I mean include packages such as `mathmex` or `gimp`.

Comment: https://packages.ubuntu.com/eoan/gimp  I don't see any depends for `gimp`  (You didn't list a release, I also looked up a second release and found no dependency for `dpkg`)

Comment: I did not mean necessarily a direct dependency. A direct example is perl-base. https://packages.ubuntu.com/cosmic/perl-base

Comment: The package you have used as example is EOL & thus off-topic on this site; I won't look or discuss that one.  https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic

Comment: @guiverc https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/perl-base *Para*: I recommend that you **[edit]** this question include one more examples in the question itself.

Answer (score 3):

In the case of `perl-base`, `dpkg` is a `Pre-Depends`, not a `Depends`. What's [`Pre-Depends`](https://www.debian.org/doc/debian-policy/ch-relationships.html)?

> This field is like Depends, except that it also forces dpkg to complete installation of the packages named before even starting the installation of the package which declares the pre-dependency[...].
>
> [...]
>
> Pre-Depends should be used sparingly, preferably only by packages whose premature upgrade or installation would hamper the ability of the system to continue with any upgrade that might be in progress.

`dpkg` was, at one time, written in Perl (and parts of it still might be written in Perl, I haven't checked the source code). So if Perl got upgraded before dpkg, it might mess things up, and cause dpkg to stop functioning. So `dpkg` has to be installed/upgraded and configured before Perl. That's why it's a `Pre-Depends`.